# Why _makepath_s does not return on error?

Tags: visual-studio, security, mfc, crt

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/makepath-s-wmakepath-s?view=vs-2019#generic-text-routine-mappings _makepath_s should return an error code on failure.

On my system this is not true, it gives an assert (Expression: (L"Buffer is too small" && 0)) and then terminates the program. In release it simply terminates the program.

The only way I found to keep my program running is to set an empty invalid parameter handler:

```
    void myInvalidParameterHandler(const wchar_t* expression,
    const wchar_t* function,
    const wchar_t* file,
    unsigned int line,
    uintptr_t pReserved)
{
}
_set_invalid_parameter_handler(myInvalidParameterHandler);
```

But this is not recommended. The docs say that this handler should abort the program.

And I also think that this modifies all secure function which is not what exactly what I want.

So is there a better way to get _makepath_s behave like the docs say?

TIA Michael

VS2017, MFC

**Edit**
A small sample:

```
    char        Path[_MAX_PATH];
char        drive[_MAX_DRIVE] = "C:";
char        dir[_MAX_DIR] = "Thisisaverylongdirname01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
char        fname[_MAX_FNAME] = "Thisisaverylongfilename012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
char        ext[_MAX_EXT] = "txt";
_makepath(Path, drive, dir, fname, ext);
```

Comment: Apparently the documentation is wrong.

Comment: It seems a issue of the documentation,I suggest you post the issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for better help. And you also may leave feedback directly on the bottom of the document.

Comment: Can we see a [mcve]?